# Failing in generating moles files for an assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mocking, moles

I have been looking at [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) for testing my entity framework generated classes and followed the steps outlined in the [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Peli/Moles-Replace-any-NET-method-with-a-delegate/) and also the [tutorial help documents](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/documentation.aspx) however I am failing at the first step.

I get the following error when adding a new moles file item ensuring that the name of the .moles file matches the assembly I have in the project.

> The custom tool 'MolesGenerator' failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have a separate test project that project references this other project I want to generate the moles assembly off.

All I have is done have installed the moles installer and I am using VS2008 with NUnit

Thanks

Comment: Which version are you using, how do you try to add the .moles file? When you do it the usual way by right clicking on the dll reference you'd like to add a moles file for, you shouldn't have to worry about the name being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Moles. Please report it on the Pex and Moles MSDN forums.